Python function to calculate distance between faces of two cylinders
I have a 3D array representing one object that is roughly a cylinder, and a 3D array representing another. I require the average distance between the faces of the adjacent cylinders. Anyone have any idea on how to do this? I was thinking of something like fitting the face of one cylinder to a plane, finding the normal and then projecting each point on that face along that normal and finding the distance to the opposing face, and averaging over all of those. It's kinda clunky though, anyone have a better more elegant solution? Would be nice if it was somewhat robust to small shape irregularities as well

Please precise. Does these objects have arbitrary orientation and rotation in space? What do you mean with average distance? If the distance doesn't have to be exact, you could also calculate the distance between two spheres with volume equal to the cylinders. Would be much faster and easier than dealing with arbitrary orientations and similar stuff

How about computing the distance between the gravity centers of each array and the mean width of each cylinder? This should allow you to approximate their distance without planes and normals.

Yes the objects have arbitrary orientation and rotation in space. What I mean by mean distance would be something like: find the minimum distance from one face to the other face for each point on one face. Then take the mean over all of those points. It would be nice to have it be accurate.
